# How can I create the following Android bash script?

Tags: android, bash, shell, scripting, adb

When I type:

```
adb devices
```

My output is (this can be variable, it can list 10 or 20 etc):

```
List of devices attached 
0280414640c133d7    device
TA054085R1  device
```

Afterwards I'd like to run:

```
adb install MyApp 0280414640c133d7
adb install MyApp TA054085R1
```

How can I get this going in a bash script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how robust you need your solution to be, but something like this will work with the case you describe above:

```
   #!/bin/bash

echo "Deploying SONR to devices..."

#install SONR
for foo in `adb devices | egrep 'device$' | cut -d ' ' -f1`
do
    adb -s $foo install SONR.apk
done
```

It is no doubt possible to replace the ugly `egrep` piped through `cut` with a single call to `sed` or `awk` or even a `perl` one-liner.

Comment: I run that script, but nothing happens.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I wrote "something like this will work".  You'll need to put in some (likely minimal) effort to get it to work with the actual output of `adb devices`.  I don't have actual output from `adb devices` available to test.  For example, maybe you need to get rid of the space in `' device$'` and get rid of the `-d' '` because it's not a space but a tab.

Comment: Thanks. I edited your answer with the corrected tweak. Thanks so much. Huge help.

Comment: You can do something like this `for foo in $(awk 'NR>1{print $1} <(adb devices))` just make sure you quote the `$foo` in the `do` section.